# How to change the amount of memory in the VM instance, the Compute Engine, and Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I create the VM instance on the Compute Engine, I chose the "E2" as the "Series" and the "e2-medium(2 vCPU, 4GB memory)" as the Machine type at the Machine configuration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQTjb.png)

After launching the VM instance, **can I change the amount of memory in the Compute Engine? And, if I can do it, I would like you to share the ways to configure it.**

This is because I'm going to install the WordPress site.

The number of traffic of the WordPress site will vary between about 2,000 PV per day and 120,000 PV per day.

With 120,000 PV of traffic per day, the Web server would not be able to respond to all the accesses with the 4GB memory initially set up. Therefore, I want to vary the amount of memory, depending on the number of traffic.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest to investigate more or at least google a little more https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance basically the search was `change vm memory gcp`

Comment: Also if you want something custom https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type

Comment: Hi, Ferregina!

Thank you for your suggestion!
When I looked at this page and especially "Changing a machine type", I noticed and understood how to switch the memory to another one. 

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance

Answer (score 1):

As the comments above have already pointed out a link, you will be able to understand how to change the amount of memory in the VM instance if you read the page.